# The right way to terminate upstart service after predetermined amount of time?

Tags: ubuntu, terminate, upstart

I need to run a nightly job (a Python process) on an Ubuntu machine using `upstart`. The service has to start every 24 hours and run for a bit longer than that, like 24.5 hours. The reason for this overlap is that the process reads from an external queue, processes the data and pushes it into a database, so stopping one service session before starting the next one will result in loss of data.

If the process crashes any time before the 24.5 hours pass, it has to be restarted, but after the 24.5 hours it has to simply stop.

What is the right way to specify this termination condition either in the `.conf` file or in the `start` command?

Answer (score 0):

1) what you basically want to achive is, that process n closes first, when process n+1 has been started.

why don't you try to assure that process n just finishes, when process n+1 has already been started with any flag like a file with some timestamp?

2) if it fails, it needs to be restarted and go on for the rest of the time till 24.5. Also then I would suggest to write that finish-time to the disk and retrieve it from there in case of a failure.